# How to override button "confirm order" in module Purchase of Odoo

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, purchase-order

I'm trying to override button "confirm order" in module "Purchase". This button will change a quotation into a purchase order (state: Purchase Confirmed), simultaneous automatically create a new receipt in module "Warehouse" so when I click button "Receive Products", I can see the receipt.

I tried to super many different functions but when i clicked the button, it just changed state, not create a new receipt. Beside, I found out that this button is from workflow and its function may be "wkf_confirm_order" but it didn't work.

```
@api.multi
def purchase_confirm(self):
    #super(purchase_order,self).wkf_bid_received()
    super(purchase_order,self).wkf_confirm_order()
    #super(purchase_order,self).wkf_approve_order()
    return True
```

Please, help me to find the correct function. I really appreciate your help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To know which function of that model will be called while you click on that button you need to follow these steps.

- Start developer mode
- Click on **Purchase Orders** menu
- Click on **EDIT WORKFLOW** option from the debug menu

[image]

- Then open that workflow record in diagram view by clicking on diagram view.

[image]

- Then it will open entire workflow of purchase order

[image]

- Click on confirm order action, it will open activity wizard from where you can see which action has been done while you click on that button.

[image]

[Click here](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/reference/workflows.html) to know more about workflow.

Answer (score 1):

This is the correct syntax of overriding a method in python

```
def my_method(self):
    #do task before my_method
    result=super(MyClass,self).my_method()
    #do task after my_method by using result
    return result
```

try this  code:

```
@api.multi
def purchase_confirm(self):
    #do task before confirm
    res=super(purchase_order,self).purchase_confirm()
    #do task after confirm by using res
    return res
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, but I want to know the the name of function of button "confirm order" that I need to override. Is it 'wkf_confirm_order' or 'wkf_approve_order' ,for example, though I tried both and it didn't correct.